# Is There Any Way to Get Current Date Time With Timezone in Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js

I've tried new Date() but it gives me GMT+0 while my timezone isn't GMT+0.
Any suggestion besides momentjs?

Answer (score -1):

`Date()` takes the **GMT** from your **system**. That means that if your GMT is wrong then your system has a wrong GMT. **Change your system's GMT from settings** and then run again the code and see the results.

Comment: I did console.log and everything is fine, I got the right timezone. Probably the problem is not the new Date() but something else. The date inserted to database is the wrong one :/

Comment: can you post a snippet of your code? that will help a lot.